# MME Audio Output Buffer Size

Tags: windows, audio

I am currently playing around with outputting FP32 samples via the old MME API (waveOutXxx functions). The problem I've bumped into is that if I provide a buffer length that does not evenly divide the sample rate, certain audible clicks appear in the audio stream; when recorded, it looks like some of the samples are lost (I'm generating a sine wave for the test). Currently I am using the "magic" value of 2205 samples per buffer for 44100 sample rate.

The question is, does anybody know the reason for these dropouts and if there is some magic formula that provides a way to compute the "proper" buffer size?

Comment: So what exactly prevents you from allocating properly aligned buffers?

Comment: In fact, nothing. It is just this requirement is not specified anywhere in MSDN. Hence, the question. If you happen to have a link where this behavior is documented properly -- please, do share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe alignment of data buffers is the value of `nBlockAlign` of [`WAVEFORMATEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

> Software must process a multiple of nBlockAlign bytes of data at a
>   time. **Data written to and read from a device must always start at the
>   beginning of a block.** For example, it is illegal to start playback of
>   PCM data in the middle of a sample (that is, on a non-block-aligned
>   boundary).

For PCM formats this is the amount of bytes for single sample across all channels. Non-PCM formats have their own alignments, often equal to length of format-specific block, e.g. 20 ms.

Back in time when `waveOutXxx` was the primary API for audio, carrying over unaligned bytes was an unreasonable burden for the API and unneeded performance overhead. Right now this API is a compatibility layer on top of other audio APIs, and I suppose that unaligned bytes are just stripped to still play the rest of the content, which would otherwise be rejected in full due to this small glitch, which might be just a smaller and non-fatal caller's inaccuracy.

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error when copying buffer data caused the glitches. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you fill the audio buffer with sine sample and play it looped , very easily it will click , unless the buffer length is not a multiple of the frequence, as you said ... the audible click in fact is a discontinuity in the wave ...an advanced techinques is to fill the buffer dinamically , that is, you should set a callback notification while the buffer pointer advance and fill the buffer with appropriate data at appropriate offset. i would use a more large buffer as 2205 is too short to get an async notification , calculate data , and write the buffer ,all that while playing , but it would depend of cpu power

Comment: I do fill the buffer dynamically, so buffers are refilled continuously and there should be no discontinuity in the data. I use three buffers, so there should be no problem with the system running out of data as well.

Comment: i would save the wav data to file and then visualize the .wav with some tools to figure out where click happens respect to buffer length and so on